# display dates in specific days using sql or php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I have these dates in table as product _dates**

9--2017-8-28

8--2017-8-27

7--2017-8-26

6--2017-8-25

5--2017-8-24

4--2017-8-23

3--2017-8-22

2--2017-8-21

1--2017-8-20

**so i want retrieve just the past 7 days from the current date as the following**

7--2017-8-28

6--2017-8-27

5--2017-8-26

4--2017-8-25

3--2017-8-24

2--2017-8-23

1--2017-8-22

**after that, i want to show these dates in specific days as the following**

7--2017-8-28

5--2017-8-26

3--2017-8-24

2--2017-8-23

1--2017-8-22

**as you see the the date number 4 and 5  will not  display them**

**how is that possible to do that??**
**i hope you understand my question**

Comment: Not sure if i follow. Do you always want dates in 3rd, 5th and 7th positions? If so , why did you list the dates in 1st and 2nd position at the end?

Comment: thanks for fast response,yes I want them in the same sequence

Comment: Aren't you skipping 4 and 6? Are you trying to only display the past 5 work days?

Comment: yes ,skipping 4 and 6 ,that what i want ,but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
SELECT product_date FROM (
    SELECT product_date , @row := @row + 1 as row, t.* 
    FROM table, (SELECT @row := 1) r
    WHERE product_date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    ORDER BY product_date DESC LIMIT 7
)
WHERE row IN (7, 5, 3, 2, 1)
```

I can't test the query right now, but I hope you got the idea:

1. Select records from last seven days
2. Add numbering to the result
3. From that result, select only rows with desired row number